# How to get Ubuntu on Chromebook without Dev Mod?

Tags: terminal, chromebook

How do you get an Ubuntu terminal on Chromebook without Developer mode? I am using a school issue chromebook.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be trying to install unauthorized software/OS is an hardware that isn't yours??

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia When I give it back at the end of the year, they will reset **everything**

Comment: Are you referring to just the terminal utility or Ubuntu with a CLI? Chromebooks are locked down to ensure that they don't become corrupted.  You need to use Dev Mod to change the OS.  You might find this interesting: https://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/.

Comment: @fixer1234 I want the terminal. I also don’t want Dev Mod

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/367333/how-is-crosh-different-than-the-linux-terminal-on-a-chromebook/

Comment: You should ask your school IT this question and they should be able to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chromebooks do not run Ubuntu, and so you will not be able to run the Ubuntu command line interface on this school-owned Chromebook. Because Chrome OS is based on Linux, however, there is a "CROSH", or ChromeOS Shell.

Whether you can access this is a matter for the school IT to decide. If they have allowed it, they will be able to tell you how to access it. If they have not allowed it, you will a) not be able to access it, or b) be in violation of the terms of your education if you do. Either way, the correct thing to do is to speak with your school IT staff regarding this.